# htaccess add parameter HOST

Tags: .htaccess

how can I add a parameter to every call of a given domain?

example:

```
www.domain1.com it always has to be added at the end ?test1=abc
www.domain2.com it always has to be added at the end ?test1=def
```

i added code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?test1=abc [L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?test1=def [L,R=301,QSA]
```

the parameter is added but there is a loop:

```
domain1.com/?test1=abc&?test1=abc&?test1=abc&?test1=abc&?test1=abc&
domain2.com/?test1=def&?test1=def&?test1=def&?test1=def&?test1=def&
```

very thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `RewriteCond` to test if the URI containing `test1` query string:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !test1=
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?test1=abc [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !test1=
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?test1=def [L,R=301,QSA]
```